# Java script stops after printing in php?

Tags: php

When the form is submit my jquery accordion stops working my file name is add.php here is its code

```
<?php require_once('database.php');?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/accordionTheme.css"> 
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#myAccordion").accordion();
    });
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="myAccordion"><!-- Start Accordion --->
        <h2>
            <a href="#">Add Student</a>
        </h2>

        <div>
            <form action="add.php" id="form1" method="get" >//here my form start
                <p>Please add Student Data</p>
                <label for="stname">Enter Student Name:</label>
                <input name="stname" type="text" id="stname" size="37" />
                <br /><br />
                <label for="stclass">Enter Student Class :</label>
                <select name="stclass">
                <option>MPhil</option>
                <option>M.Sc.</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input name="Add" type="submit" id="Add" value="Add" />
            </form>
            <?php
            //lets start submit data to database
            if(isset($_GET['stname'])&& isset($_GET['stclass']))
            {
                $stname=$_GET['stname'];
                $stclass=$_GET['stclass'];

                if(mysql_query("insert into student(teacher_id,student_name,student_class) values ('1','$stname','$stclass')"));
                {
                    print "<p>record added</p";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <h2>
            <a href="#">Add course</a>
        </h2>

        <div></div>

        <h2>
            <a href="#">Add publication</a>
        </h2>

        <div></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I am printing php inside body you can see `recordadded` when form is submitted.

Comment: Close the `p` tag in the printed line ;)

Comment: @mingos thanks it worked thanks you can give it anser i will accept it

Comment: done, and glad I could help :)

Comment: Man, I just formatted your code the way I usually format mine. It's just you to see how things get a bit more clear with the some indentation. It's important !! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `p` tag you print using PHP is not closed, which is what makes JavaScript go crazy. Close it and it should work OK.